# Hide the "1 usage" indicator floating in code editor in IntelliJ 2020

Tags: intellij-idea

Somehow I did something to make IntelliJ indicate a number of usages for each variable on a class. Text such as "1 usage" appears above each variable declaration.

How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

See the `Show hints` section of `Code Vision` in Preferences/Settings under `Editor` > `Java`. See [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/inlay-hints-java.html#lenses).

You may uncheck the `Usages` item as it seen in the screenshot.

[image]

IntelliJ 2020.2 gains a new third checkbox, `Broken usages`, along with the `Usages` & `Inheritors` items.

Intellij 2022.2 reorganized the inlay hints preferences, so the option is in a different place:

[image]

Comment: Correct, thanks. By the way, my IntelliJ 2020.2 shows a third checkbox under "Show hints for:" labeled "Broken usages".

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks for informing - i just checked the updates but it says no updates available. I use IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2 (Ultimate Edition) - maybe different editions.

Comment: 2020.2 is in [early-release](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/), not final yet. I cannot find any documentation for this new feature of `Broken usages`.

Comment: @Ersoy Intellij 2022 reorganized these preferences a bit. You may wish to update your answer.

Comment: hey @Kenster thank you for the heads-up but i have the most recent versions. You may edit my answer or add a new answer if you prefer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer for 2023, the setting is called "code vision"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can right click on ***usages*** and select one of the "Hide ... Inlay Hints" options from the pop-up:

[image: screenshot]