# How to turn off usages warnings in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I would like to disable where it says in the editor above the line it refers to, "3 usages", "2 usages", etc, in grey, but leave them there when they're red. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: You should clarify what you're referring to, maybe with a screenshot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide the "1 usage" indicator floating in code editor in IntelliJ 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62352043/hide-the-1-usage-indicator-floating-in-code-editor-in-intellij-2020)

Comment: no i cant find that setting

Comment: I am able to find and disable that setting based on that post.